# getting the row with the correct data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structe like belwo, whith data combine with objectid

```
SELECT 
    OBJECTID, MODEL
FROM 
    VEND_REPORTS.CHILD_APP_DATA
WHERE 
    OBJECTID= '1257300';
```

Sample values in my table:

```
objectid   model 
1257300 CVC Town Car (2004-)-2006
1257300 CVC Town Car (2004-)-2005
1257300 CVC Town Car (2004-)-2008
1257300 CVC Town Car (2004-)-200
```

the way i want to see the data is just pick the 
 2004-208  cvc town car

i tried couple of things  but nothing seem to be working 
any starting point would be great . thanks in advance

Comment: u mean u want to select the row with model 'CVC Town Car (2004-)-2008' ?

Comment: yes but there are other column that have the same  same datatype but different values so really caint do the hard coding  here

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps you,

```
select objectid, model
from VEND_REPORTS.CHILD_APP_DATA
where model like '%2004-208 cvc town car%'
```

updated: new suggestion

if the model value's format is fixed like

```
 "CVC Town Car (" "year" "-)-" "year"
```

, you can user split of string based on fixed sub-strings

if the model values's format is not fixed, then use regular expression to find the series of continuous 4 digits, so you will end up with two numbers.

Comment: this did not help you are hard coding the values i dont want that  i want to group it by the object id  and then select the from min number to max   whihc is ofcourse  (2004-2008 cvc town car) for this object id .

Comment: you are looking for processing the model columns data before selecting  it.. right!!! like you want to break down the varchar "CVC Town Car (2004-)-2008" so that you can check for 2004 and 2008?

Comment: can you go bit more explaining, of what i have understood i would suggest to use PL/SQL plain SQL wont help you much for this requirement.

Comment: yes that would be correct  but what my concern is the 2004 -2008 could be changing it could be differnt number for other objectid  for exameple  2003-2005.. i tried spliting the column but from alphabati and number but there are model with only number so its was no go